# TypeError while looping through a variable list of files with subprocess commands

Tags: python, loops, subprocess, typeerror

As background, I have created a list with elements of different filenames with their full path `(/.../filea.dat)` called `fileList`, it is of variable length. It has the form `fileList = ['/../filea.dat', '/../fileb.dat']`.

I would like to execute a subprocess command on every file in that list of files, then later analyze the components of each of the files (and generated new files) separately.

```
for i, elem in enumerate(fileList):
   hexed = fileList[i]
   subprocess.Popen("hexdump " + hexed + " > hexed.dat", shell=True)

   with open("hexed.dat", "r") as f:
      for line in f:
         if "statement" in line:
            value = "examplevalue"
   if value == "examplevalue"
      other subprocess statements that create a file that will again be used later
```

Right now I have a `TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'list' objects`. Let me know if I'm on the right track with this method approach as well.

Please let me know if I need to provide additional clarification; I tried to simplify to the basics as the other details aren't important to the issue.

Comment: 1- if you want to fix the `TypeError` then ask about the `TypeError` (though the error message seems pretty clear. [edit] your question and add the complete traceback). Thus your question might be useful to somebody else too.  If you want to know how to read a subprocess output line by line then ask about that (though there are many existing questions already). If you want to know how to hexlify a file in Python; you can ask about it too as a separate question (you don't need  to run `hexdump`) Try to limit your questions to a single issue per question.

Comment: I can see how me having multipart question isn't ideal, but for me many of the issues tie together. While, as you say, there are other options for hexdump I am using the subprocess to perform other things beside hexdump, that was just an easy portion to convey here. I assure you I have been looking at other questions, I just simply didn't find those answers helpful for my situation so I posted my question.

Comment: there are common questions in [the subprocess tag info](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/subprocess/info)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are close. You got the type error because `Popen` requires that you also set `shell=True` when passing in a string instead of a list. But there is another problem: `Popen` doesn't wait for the process to complete so when you read the file, there isn't anything useful in it yet. A different strategy is to skip file redirection and read the output stream directly. Note also that you don't need to use `enumerate`... the for loop gets the values in the list already. And we can skip the shell and pass the command as a list.

```
for hexed in fileList:
    proc = subprocess.Popen(["hexdump", hexed], stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
        stderr=open(os.devnull, 'w'))
    for line in proc.stdout:
        if "statement" in line:
            value = "examplevalue"
    proc.wait()
    if proc.returncode != 0:
        print('error') # need less lame error handling!   
    if value == "examplevalue"
        other subprocess statements that create a file that will again be
```

Comment: I actually did have shell=True I don't know how I missed adding that into my question. I have made your adjustments and it does seem to be properly executing now. But originally I wanted that output to go into a file as I'll have other parts of my code look at those generated files and generate additional files. I don't think i can pull the stdout shortcut later on I'll have to generate those files.